# VIEWS IN SQL ORACLE QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, database

TABLE DESC:

```
Product (Prodid, Prodesc, Price, Stock)
Sales (Saleid, Proid, qty, custname)
```

QUERY:

```
Create a view which displays Proid, Prodesc and sum of quantity in sales.
```

I ve tried many times creating the view but lead to an error like NOT SINGLE GROUP FUNCTION,NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION. Solution Please.

ERRORS:

a) NOT GROUP BY:

```
create or replace view sale_vs as select * from(select prodesc,proid,sum(qt
y) from sales,product group by proid);
```

b) NOT SINGLE GROUP:

```
create or replace view sale_vs as select product.prodid,product.prodesc,sum
(qty) from product,sales where sales.proid=product.prodid;
```

Comment: That would be cheating ;-) What SQL have you tried?  Show us and we can perhaps point out where you are going wrong.  Never mind creating a view for now, just write the SELECT statement it would be based on.

Comment: Now?... Where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Thanks.  Well, a rule of writing aggregate queries is that all the columns in the SELECT clause that are not aggregate functions (SUM etc.) must also be specified in the GROUP BY clause - so `SELECT a,b,c,SUM(d) FROM x GROUP BY a,b,c` for example.

Comment: It is not coming :( I tried this query.. create or replace view myView as select proid,prodesc,sum(qty) from product
,sales group by proid,prodesc; .. Error: ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias

Comment: can you post some sample data..

Comment: `"ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias"` means that in a view definition you must give all the columns names. `proid` and `prodesc` can automatically be turned into column names for the view, but `sum(qty)` cannot - you must name this e.g. `sum(qty) as total_qty`

Comment: Answer found: create or replace view myView as select * from ( select proid,prodesc,sum(q
ty) from product,sales where sales.proid=product.prodid group by proid,prodesc);
View created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:-

```
create or replace view myView as
select p.Prodid Product_ID, p.Prodesc Product_description, sum(s.qty) Sum_of_qty
from product p, sales s where p.Prodid= s.Proid group by p.prodid, p.prodesc
```

Here's the sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02820/2

Comment: it says ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "P"."PROID": invalid identifier :(

Comment: Actually this is the error: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias